# Is there any way I can get through the door to the staircase in Castle Panteer?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I made my character the largest size possible; that was a mistake.  On Alderaan I'm trying to get the datacron in Castle Panteer, but I'm getting stuck on the door to the staircase:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way I can fit through here?  I looked through the preferences for a "roll" move or something else that would help but didn't find anything.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question made me laugh so hard... I don't know why! +1 for apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually fixed in Patch 1.2!  Awesome.

Comment: Voted to close as Too Localized.

Answer (score 9):

At the moment, this is a bug in the game. You cannot access that datacron because you're too fat (couldn't resist).

There are a few ways to get past this (that I've read, I gave up on that datacron personally):

- You can duel someone that is smaller and use a charge ability when they are on the other side. (looks like you're a Jedi/Sith warrior from that screenshot).
- You can have a friendly Jedi/Sith healer of a smaller size go with you and grip you in.
- You can duel a bounty hunter/storm trooper friend(Tank advanced class), who is a smaller size and have them grapple you.